# Javascript: assign onclick inside class

Tags: javascript, html, class, onclick

I created a constructor that will handle a custom list control. I created a method in order to allow the user to add elements to the list, and I need to assign event handlers to the click events of the list elements (divs).

A simplified version of the code is here. The list elements are created using the innerHTML property and a string template upon which I substitute specific parts. Later I get the element by it's id and assign it a function in closure:

```
function prueba(){
    var plantilla = '<div id="«id»">«texto»</div>';

    var f = function(nombre){
        return function(){console.log('mi nombre es ' + nombre)};
    };

    this.agregar = function(id, texto){
        var tmp = plantilla.replace('«id»', id);
        tmp = tmp.replace('«texto»', texto);
        document.body.innerHTML += tmp;

        document.getElementById(id).onclick = f(id);
    };
};
```

The problem is that, apparently, the event handler is unasigned to previous created divs, so is only retained by the last one, as it can be tested with the following code:

```
var p = new prueba;

p.agregar('i1', 'texto1');
console.log(document.getElementById('i1').onclick.toString());//shows the function code
p.agregar('i2', 'texto2');
console.log(document.getElementById('i2').onclick.toString());//shows the function code
console.log(document.getElementById('i1').onclick.toString());//returns 'null' error
p.agregar('i3', 'texto3');
console.log(document.getElementById('i3').onclick.toString());//shows the function code
console.log(document.getElementById('i2').onclick.toString());//returns 'null' error
```

This happens in Iceweasel as well as in Chromium. It does NOT happen when I add 'onclick = f(«id»)' in the template (which I cannot do here because of the assigned function scope), and neither happens if I use document.createElement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You destroy elements previously created when you do this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += tmp;
```

Instead use `insertAdjacentHMTL()` if you want to append using HTML markup.

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tmp);
```

Now instead of going through this destructive process...

1. serialize the existing DOM nodes to HTML
2. concatenate the new HTML fragment to the serialized nodes
3. destroy the old nodes
4. recreate the nodes with the new nodes

...it simply creates the new content and places it before the close of the `body` element.

Basically, remove `element.innerHTML += ...` from your coding practices. It's never necessary, it's inefficient and it causes problems like what you've described.

---

FYI, the `.insertAdjacentHTML()` method receives 4 different string possibilities as the first argument. Each one designates a position relative to the element on which you're calling it.

The strings are...

- `"beforebegin"`
- `"afterbegin"`
- `"beforeend"`
- `"afterend"`

The labels are pretty self-explanatory. They position the new content before the current element, inside the current element at the beginning, inside the current element at the end, or after the current element, respectively.

---

Your full code will look like this, which I shortened a bit too since the `tmp` really isn't needed here:

```
function prueba(){
    var plantilla = '<div id="«id»">«texto»</div>';

    var f = function(nombre){
        return function(){console.log('mi nombre es ' + nombre)};
    };

    this.agregar = function(id, texto){
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
                                             plantilla.replace('«id»', id)
                                                      .replace('«texto»', texto));

        document.getElementById(id).onclick = f(id);
    };
};
```

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML indeed solves the problem, thanks!. I just have a further doubt: you say that this destroys the elements previously created, but the only thing that is destroyed is the function assigned to them (I actually see the new divs with their corresponding text) Is the function considered a new element?

Comment: @CarlosPrieto: It does destroy the elements as well as anything associated with them, like event handler functions. It then recreates them. This is very inefficient. Say you have a total of 100 DOM nodes in the `body`. What happens is that the JS engine needs to traverse through *every* node, convert them to a string of HTML, add your new HTML to the end of that string, destroy the old nodes, parse the HTML you just created, create new nodes and put them in the `body`. So yes, it basically destroys them and then recreates them, which is wasteful.

Comment: ...there *may* be some optimizations to make it slightly more efficient than that, but who knows. The principle is destructive, and definitely wipes out event handlers and other stuff, so the `.insertAdjacentHTML` helps immensely.